# Selenium Python: How to fetch text/html data from <script> tag with javascript file from a web page?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

The code looks like this:

```
<script async="" id="__NEXT_PAGE__/restaurants" src="/_next/static/~k5VPZk5KBtLKJOP7fLbR/pages/restaurants.js"></script>

<script async="" id="__NEXT_PAGE__/_app" src="/_next/static/~k5VPZk5KBtLKJOP7fLbR/pages/_app.js"></script>

<script async="" src="/_next/static/chunks/146.5cc25d7743407960833f.js"></script>

<script src="/_next/static/runtime/webpack-562f11f96da3918c3d37.js" async=""></script>

<script src="/_next/static/chunks/styles.4fc2149595e9293ccd52.js" async=""></script>

<script src="/_next/static/chunks/styles.4fc2149595e9293ccd52.js" async=""></script>
```

I used

**webdriver.Chrome().find_element_by_id("**NEXT_PAGE**/restaurants").get_attribute("innerHtml")** and

**webdriver.Chrome().find_element_by_xpath("//script[@src='/_next/static/chunks/136.ff85cd2297a8e5bf9619.js']").get_attribute("innerHtml")**

but they returned **None**.

I am not really sure if there is text inside the tag btw. This is the page: https://food.grab.com/ph/en/restaurants

I am trying to fetch latitude and longitude for restaurants on the pages after pressing 'load more' button. This info is available in  tag with id = '**NEXT_DATA**' for first 16 restaurants but beyond that it seems to be hidden somewhere. I know python but not javascript.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the question. Maybe fixing it would help you.

Comment: @Onur Isn't it javascript file inside src (src='/_next/static/chunks/136.ff85cd2297a8e5bf9619.js)?

Comment: No I mean you said. **The code looks like this.** and there is no code

Comment: @onur Got it. Thank you for heads up!

Comment: Update the question with a bit more of the HTML

Comment: @DebanjanB Updated with more code and link as well.

Comment: Oops, need the parent tag of the `<script>` tag